# VB 6 legacy app migration to Oracle 11g

Tags: vb6, odbc, oracle11g

I have a legacy VB (visual basic) 6 application that connects to Oracle 8 database. We have to migrate this to Oracle 11g. (Heads up: I have never worked on VB)

The application is shipped to 1000+ users as an EXE file. Here is what i need help on:

For Developers, I understand they will need to install new oracle client for the ODBC drivers and once they test their application on 11g. Once they are done they will publish a new EXE file.

Users, Will install this new EXE file but will this be sufficient ? or the users will need to install something extra other than the new application (like a oracle 11g client, DLL files etc) on their end as well ?

Can a VB 6 app be packaged in such a way that it copies all the DLL/dependencies along with it so that end users do not need to install anything else ?

-- Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe the previous developers just copied the EXE file!  I know that the run-time is installed on most recent versions of Windows, but that is ridiculous!

You can use VB6's "Package and Deployment Wizard".  Why not try it out?  It will pick up all components contained in the References and Components dialogues, and any DLLs referenced in a Declare statement.  However, if those components have dependencies, you might have to add them manually.